# show HASHMAP values separately in onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I am using HASHMAP to show two items in a single list item of list as shown in the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
HashMap<String, String> item;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };

    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    // setOnItemClickListener(selectLesson);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int    position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Map<String, String> nn = list.get(position);

    String item1 = (String)           getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
    // item.get(name);


    Toast.makeText(this, item1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    list.add(putData("Android", "Mobile"));
    list.add(putData("Windows7", "Windows7"));
    list.add(putData("iPhone", "iPhone"));
    return list;
}

private HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
    item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("name", name);
    item.put("purpose", purpose);


    return item;
}

}
```

What I want is that whenever I click a listitem key value should be displayed in separate toasts.Currently I am showing both in a single toast and dont know how to separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click on a row, `onListItemClick` is fired. You can retrieve the element you click with `getItemAtPosition`:

```
HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

and to retrieve the info from the item use the get method

```
 String string = item.get("the_key_you_want_to_retrieve");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code

```
String item1 = (String)getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, item1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

By

```
String item1 = getListAdapter().getItem(position).getString("name");
   String item2 = getListAdapter().getItem(position).getString("purpose");
    Toast.makeText(this, item1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, item2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Note**

"name" --> first key as per your choice

"purpose" --> second key as per your choice

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function to split the "item1"

```
String item1=(String)getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
String[] parts = item1.split(" ");
String part1 = parts[0]; // Android
String part2 = parts[1]; // Mobile
 Toast.makeText(this, part1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Toast.makeText(this, part2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Split function is used to split string according to given condition. I am using here space (" ") to split item1 into two strings.

Comment: its showing output like first toast {PURPOSE=MOBILE, 2nd toast NAME=ANDROID} i only want to show MOBILE and ANDROID